# Django inheritance: specify foreign key name

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-3.5

I'm new to the Django world, and am using Django REST Framework, but I don't think this is relevant to my problem.

I designed my database by hand and prefer not to use Django migrations to generate it. I have as a convention to use the name `tablename_id` as a foreign key.

My problem is that when I want to use inheritance, Django tries to use the name `parenttablename_ptr_id` instead of `parenttablename_id`. Is there a way to specify this ?

Here is some fake code showing wanted result:

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
class B(A):
    # some other stuff
    # a_id as a foreign key to A, instead of a_ptr_id
```

I hope this was clear, I couldn't find an answer elsewhere.

Thank you in advance for your response !

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#specifying-the-parent-link-field

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted ! Thank you !